# How to find which element of an array of a table of database contain the same substring of a string that user input PhP

Tags: php, mysql

Teachers want to search the name of the students using this system, but they only remember part of his name. So , they input that part of name into the search box and hopfully get the full  name:

Here is my code:

```
$data_player = "SELECT * FROM tableplayer";  
$result_player= $conn -> query($data_player);
$thearray= $result_player->fetch_assoc();
```

set up variables to avoid undefined index:

```
  $Mark=0;
      $EndOfSearch=False;
      $SearchStudentName="";
```

The following code is the basic logic that I have to solve the problem. but it just doesn't work. The web told me that  "The search engine part 2 is triggered sucessfully" but no results have been output.
I use mock data "test1" and "test2" and input "test" in the search.

```
     
         if( in_array($SearchKeyword,$thearray)== false  AND strlen($_GET["keyword"])>=3 ){// search engine part 2
         echo "<br>The search engine part 2 is triggered sucessfully";
             
                 For($y=1;$y<sizeof($thearray);$y++){  
                 For($x=0;$x<strlen($_GET["keyword"]);$x++){
                     $tempcheck=$_GET["keyword"][$x];
                 
                if ($thearray[$y][$x] == $tempcheck){
                $Mark++;
                if($Mark >= 3){
                    
                $SearchStudentName= query("SELECT Name,Grade,StudentID FROM tablePlayer WHERE Name ='$thearray[$y][$x]'"); 
                while($row2=$SearchStudentName->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo "Are you looking for"." <a href=individualpage.php?id=".$row['StudentID'].">".$row2['name'].$row2['Grade'].$row2['StudentID']."</a> " ;
                                
                }
                     $EndOfSearch=True;
                
                }else{
                    $mark=0;
                    $y++; // this might be problemsome. because if we use y++ i dont really know if the code will be exectcute correctly                
                }        
                }
                 }
                 
             }}
                 Else {Echo " student not found";}}
```

Comment: Seems like you would need the LIKE keyword in SQL. It's a bit unclear what all the looping at the start of the PHP is for. What does $thearray contain?

Comment: . I use that those loops to get characters of element of an array..

Comment: thearray is the associate array that contain ALL from The Table-player

Comment: Ok. that makes no sense. Learn how to use a LIKE query instead...much more efficient.

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/

Answer (score 0):

honestly my teacher asked me to do the same so i will share with you what i did

**1. THE TABLE**
here is the table I used

```
mysql> select *from inf_parent ;
+-----------+---------------+---------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| id_parent | Parent_Nom    | Parent_Prenom | Parent_Tel | Parent_Fille | filleClasse |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
|         1 | Elmoctare     | Brahim        | 773244176  | Maka         | ClasseA     |
|         2 | moustapha     | mbaye         | 780157046  | dior         | ClasseB     |
|         3 | Mustaph Mbaye | Diallo        | 771234569  | marietou     | ClasseA     |
|         4 | Demba Thiam   | Amadou        | 771245874  | dijaa        | ClasseC     |
|         5 | Senghor Mbaye | Mbaye         | 771278596  | fakane       | ClasseA     |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

`Parent_Nom` = parent name

`Parent_Prenom` = parent last name

`Parent_Tel` = parent phone number

`Parent_Fille` = parent child (Student in the school)

`fille_Classe` = child class

let me explain the idea is that the school must be able to find the name of a parent even if it knows a small part of his name so to do that I used `php` with `jquery`

So to do that I created two files

**2. fetch.php**

```
<?php
//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "passer", "ape"); // database parameters
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]); // protect your query from sql injection
$query = "
 SELECT * FROM inf_parent WHERE Parent_Nom LIKE '%".$request."%' OR Parent_Prenom LIKE '%".$request."%'
LIMIT 4"; 
/*LIKE is used in the WHERE clause of SQL queries. 
This keyword is used to search for a particular model. For example, it is possible 
to search for records where the value of a column begins with a particular letter. 
The research models are multiple.
*/
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$data = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     
 $data[] = $row["Parent_Nom"];
 $data[] = $row["Parent_Prenom"];
}
 echo json_encode($data); //echo data
}
?>
```

So basically we send requests to our database looking for the name of a parent or the first name of a parent which begins with a letter gives

**3. index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <title>Display</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
         <head>     
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
         </head>
 <body>
    <?php
    // bdd is a query which allows the connection of the database
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ape', 'root', 'passer') OR die("Error in the connection to the database");

    ?>

    <div class="container">
    <br/>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
            <form class="card card-sm" action="" method="post">
             <div class="card-body row no-gutters align-items-center">
              <div class="col-auto">
                <i class="fas fa-search h4 text-body"></i>
                  </div>
                   <!--end of col-->
                    <div class="col">
                <input type = "search" name = "terme" id="terme" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" size="4" placeholder="Rechercher un nom">      
                </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                      <input type = "submit" name = "s" value = "Rechercher" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                    </div>      
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['s']))
        {
         $terme =  htmlspecialchars($_POST["terme"]); //to secure the form against html vulnerabilities;
         $terme = trim($terme); //to remove spaces in the Internet user's request
         $terme = strip_tags($terme); //to remove the html tags in the request
         if (isset($terme) AND !empty($terme))
            {
             $terme = strtolower($terme);
             $select_terme = $bdd->prepare("SELECT *FROM inf_parent WHERE Parent_Nom LIKE ? OR Parent_Prenom LIKE ?");
             $select_terme->execute(array("%".$terme."%", "%".$terme."%"));
         }
        }
        ?>
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('#terme').typeahead({
  source: function(query, result)
  {

   $.ajax({
    url:"fetch.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{query:query},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
    console.log(data);
     result($.map(data, function(item){
      return item;
     }));
    }
   })
  }
 });
 
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image: output]

as you can see it work for me